# Alignment problem in math mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath, alignat

I'm having troubles in aligning some items in this MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    AAAAA &= BBBBBB \\
    &&= CCCCCC + DDDDDDD,
\\[1ex]
    EEE &= FFFFFFF \\
    &&= 38 \, GGGGGGGG + 45 \, HHHHHHH,
\\[1ex]
    KKKKKKKKK &= LL \\
    &&= MM + N.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

The real lines in my code that I identified with $CCC\dots + DDD\dots$, $38 GGG \dots$ and $MM + N$ are actually pretty long and cannot be aligned with the parts above them ($BBB\dots$, etc).  However, I would like them to be aligned like this:

[image]

So how can I achieve this?

In other words, the short lines (1), (3) and (5) should stay aligned together, while the much longer lines (2), (4) and (6) should be aligned together.

---

**EDIT**  Here's the real life maths output I have, from three choices.  The first one is a simple *align* environment, but the long parts goes in the right marging.  The second version is a *gather* environment with three seperately aligned parts.  The third version is a simple *align*, with a negative space, as suggested by some of the answers below.  So which one is the best less confusing output?

[image]

As requested by egreg in the comments, I'm adding the (simplified) code that makes the last picture:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

Blabla bla bla bla blablabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla:
\begin{align*}
    \tensor{\gamma}{_i} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_j} + \tensor{\gamma}{_j} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_i} &= (\, \tensor{a}{_i} + a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} ) + (\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} + a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &= \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} + a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag} = 2 \, \tensor{\delta}{_{ij}}, \\[1ex]
    \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, j}} + \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, j}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} &= -\: (\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} - a_j^{\dag} ) - (\, \tensor{a}{_j} - a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &= -\: \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} + a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} - a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} - \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} - a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag} = 2 \, \tensor{\delta}{_{ij}}, \\[1ex]
    \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_j} + \tensor{\gamma}{_j} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} &= -\: i  (\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} ) - i  (\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &= -\: i \, \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} - i \, \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} + i \, a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + i \, a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} - i \, \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + i \, \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} - i \, a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + i \, a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag} = 0.
\end{align*}
Blabla bla bla bla blablabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla:
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
    \tensor{\gamma}{_i} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_j} + \tensor{\gamma}{_j} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_i} &= (\, \tensor{a}{_i} + a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} ) + (\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} + a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &= \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} + a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag} = 2 \, \tensor{\delta}{_{ij}},
\end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
    \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, j}} + \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, j}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} &= -\: (\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} - a_j^{\dag} ) - (\, \tensor{a}{_j} - a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &= -\: \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} + a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} - a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} - \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} - a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag} = 2 \, \tensor{\delta}{_{ij}},
\end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
    \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_j} + \tensor{\gamma}{_j} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} &= -\: i  (\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} ) - i  (\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &= -\: i  \bigl( \, \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} - a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} - a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} - \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} - a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag}  \bigr) = 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
Blabla bla bla bla blablabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla:
\begin{align*}
    \tensor{\gamma}{_i} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_j} + \tensor{\gamma}{_j} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_i} &= (\, \tensor{a}{_i} + a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} ) + (\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} + a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &\hspace{-2cm}= \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} + a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag} = 2 \, \tensor{\delta}{_{ij}},
\\[1ex]
    \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, j}} + \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, j}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} &= -\: (\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} - a_j^{\dag} ) - (\, \tensor{a}{_j} - a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &\hspace{-2cm}= -\: \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} + a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} - a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} - \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} - a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag} = 2 \, \tensor{\delta}{_{ij}},
\\[1ex]
    \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_j} + \tensor{\gamma}{_j} \, \tensor{\gamma}{_{n \,+\, i}} &= -\: i  (\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} ) - i  (\, \tensor{a}{_j} + a_j^{\dag} )(\, \tensor{a}{_i} - a_i^{\dag} ) \\
    &\hspace{-2cm}= -\: i  \bigl( \, \tensor{a}{_i} \: \tensor{a}{_j} + \tensor{a}{_i} \: a_j^{\dag} - a_i^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_j} - a_i^{\dag} \: a_j^{\dag} + \tensor{a}{_j} \: \tensor{a}{_i} - \tensor{a}{_j} \: a_i^{\dag} + a_j^{\dag} \: \tensor{a}{_i} - a_j^{\dag} \: a_i^{\dag}  \bigr) = 0.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please be move specific as to what you are trying, it is not particularly clear, the last image in particularly does not make any sense to me. Additionally, you specified 2 alignment columns, thus each row needs 3 `&`'s, two to make alignments and one to separate the alignment groups.

Comment: @daleif, the alignat environment was used only to built this MWE.  It doesn't work well for what I want to achieve, but currently it was the best bet I had.

Comment: @Cham Can you please add the code for the picture, so we have something to play with?

Comment: @egreg, you mean the full code of the last picture?  It's really a complicated code, with several packages loaded!

Comment: @Cham I see no reason for several packages. Just add the code for the displays.

Comment: @egreg, I added the full code, with some simplifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but you're the cause of your own troubles.

There are too many arbitrary added spaces, that make the formulas harder to read, both in the code and in the output. The use of `\tensor` can be avoided and the subscripts be vertically aligned nonetheless.

I define a `\ts` command that prints a phantom superscript dag, if not called as `\ts*` (that also recalls transposition).

By removing the added spacings, the formulas fit in the assigned text width. I also decided to align also the last equals signs in the formulas, so they're not lost by the reader at the end of a very long term.

[image]

The code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ts}{sm}{%
 #2\IfBooleanTF{#1}{^{\dag}}{^{\vphantom{\dag}}}%
}

\begin{document}

Blabla bla bla bla blablabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla
bla bla bla blablabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla
bla bla bla blablabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla
\begin{align*}
\ts{\gamma}_{i} \ts{\gamma}_{j} + \ts{\gamma}_{j} \ts{\gamma}_{i} 
&= ( \ts{a}_{i} + \ts*{a}_i )( \ts{a}_{j} + \ts*{a}_j ) 
 +( \ts{a}_{j} + \ts*{a}_j )( \ts{a}_{i} + \ts*{a}_i )
\\
&= \ts{a}_{i} \ts{a}_{j} + \ts{a}_{i} \ts*{a}_j
  +\ts*{a}_i \ts{a}_{j} + \ts*{a}_i \ts*{a}_j
  +\ts{a}_{j} \ts{a}_{i} + \ts{a}_{j} \ts*{a}_i + \ts*{a}_j \ts{a}_{i} 
  +\ts*{a}_j \ts*{a}_i
\\
&= 2\ts{\delta}_{ij},
\\[1ex]
\ts{\gamma}_{n + i} \ts{\gamma}_{n + j} + \ts{\gamma}_{n + j} \ts{\gamma}_{n + i}
&=-( \ts{a}_{i} - \ts*{a}_i )( \ts{a}_{j} - \ts*{a}_j )
  -( \ts{a}_{j} - \ts*{a}_j )( \ts{a}_{i} - \ts*{a}_i )
\\
&=-\ts{a}_{i} \ts{a}_{j} + \ts{a}_{i} \ts*{a}_j + \ts*{a}_i \ts{a}_{j}
  -\ts*{a}_i \ts*{a}_j - \ts{a}_{j} \ts{a}_{i} + \ts{a}_{j} \ts*{a}_i
  +\ts*{a}_j \ts{a}_{i} - \ts*{a}_j \ts*{a}_i
\\
&= 2\ts{\delta}_{ij},
\\[1ex]
\ts{\gamma}_{n + i} \ts{\gamma}_{j} + \ts{\gamma}_{j} \ts{\gamma}_{n + i}
&=-i( \ts{a}_{i} - \ts*{a}_i )( \ts{a}_{j} + \ts*{a}_j )
  -i( \ts{a}_{j} + \ts*{a}_j )( \ts{a}_{i} - \ts*{a}_i )
\\
&=-i\ts{a}_{i} \ts{a}_{j} - i \ts{a}_{i} \ts*{a}_j
  +i\ts*{a}_i \ts{a}_{j} + i \ts{a}_i \ts*{a}_j
  -i\ts{a}_{j} \ts{a}_{i} + i \ts{a}_{j} \ts*{a}_i
  -i\ts*{a}_j \ts{a}_{i} + i \ts*{a}_j \ts*{a}_i
\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very very nice....the emoji  and the answer.

Comment: Why the \ts macro?  Why not the tensor command, which gives the right index position anyway?

Comment: @Cham A much more efficient one.

Comment: More efficient in what respect?  The tensor package does everything I need for the index positions.

Comment: Oh, and I fully agree about the last equality, which should be on a separate line.  I've done it this way so save vertical space, but it appears that adding a new line is actually much better!

Comment: @Cham About efficiency: do you think its better `\tensor{a}{_i} a_j^{\dag}` or `\ts{a}_{i}\ts*{a}_j`? I'd have no doubt. ;-)

Comment: @egreg, well, the indices have nothing to do with the hermitian conjugate, so I don't think it's a good idea to mix them in a macro.  Also, I did defined a special macro to place the \dag at a proper position when there are some index (wathever its position).  So I don't need a special macro for the indices.  I don't mind typing a bit more with the tensor package.  My code is easy to read and understand (to my eyes, at least).  And sometimes, a quantity does have indices in the upper position too!

Answer (score 5):

Your alignment is out as on the even numbered rows you are missing a `&` so the fragments are right aligned not left, this is shown in the first block, but it appears you want the alignment in the second block (which seems a bit confusing but...)

The negative spacing in the requested form completely obscures the mathematics: the = that are referring to the same value are *not* aligned, but = referring to different values *are* aligned.

If the values are too wide to align all the = I would align = that refer to the same value, but allow the individual equations to align separately as in ccc

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

aaa
\begin{alignat}{2}
    AAAAA &= BBBBBB \\
    &&&= CCCCCC + DDDDDDD,
\\[1ex]
    EEE &= FFFFFFF \\
    &&&= 38 \, GGGGGGGG + 45 \, HHHHHHH,
\\[1ex]
    KKKKKKKKK &= LL \\
    &&&= MM + N.
\end{alignat}


bbb
\begin{alignat}{1}
    AAAAA &= BBBBBB \\
    &\hspace{-1cm}= CCCCCC + DDDDDDD,
\\[1ex]
    EEE &= FFFFFFF \\
    &\hspace{-1cm}= 38 \, GGGGGGGG + 45 \, HHHHHHH,
\\[1ex]
    KKKKKKKKK &= LL \\
    &\hspace{-1cm}= MM + N.
\end{alignat}



ccc
\begin{align}
    AAAAA &= BBBBBB \\
    &= CCCCCC + DDDDDDD,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    EEE &= FFFFFFF \\
    &= 38 \, GGGGGGGG + 45 \, HHHHHHH,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    KKKKKKKKK &= LL \\
    &= MM + N.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then the alignat becomes useless, and should be replaced with a simple align instead?  But then, the lines (2), (4) and (6) are a bit too long and goes outside the right margin.

Comment: @Cham I would use `align` rather than `alignat` for both of these forms but I kept `alignat` as that is what you had. The examples here are not too long and do not go out of the margin, if your your real examples in your real document do then that is a possibility, but then you can use the second more compact form.

Comment: I admit that the real maths are getting confusing without all equal signs aligned for all lines.  But then, should I let some of the lines getting a bit inside the right margin?  It looks a bit ugly!

Comment: @Cham some journals would simply refuse to print if the text is sticking in the margin so that may be completely forbidden and will be ugly as you say. Without seeing the real example it's hard to say, usually you can break the right hand side somewhere

Comment: The negative space is a nifty trick.  I may use it.

Comment: I'll add the real output in the question, to show the three alternatives I currently have.

Comment: @Cham I added a third possibility

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\z#1{\llap{$\mathrlap{\displaystyle#1}$\hspace{3.5em}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    AAAAA &= BBBBBB \\
    &\z{= CCCCCC + DDDDDDD,}
\\[1ex]
    EEE &= FFFFFFF \\
    &\z{= 38 \, GGGGGGGG + 45 \, HHHHHHH,}
\\[1ex]
    KKKKKKKKK &= LL \\
    &\z{= MM + N.}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you might want to add `\displaystyle` inside your rlap as you can't tell here with just AAA but you are setting rows alternating   textstyle then displaystyle, but+1 for the excellent macro name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Will do.  I was merely paying homage to the master.